# Propositional logic, could this question be a typo?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I'm trying to derive conclusions from premisies in a propositional logic class, and I believe the below question has a typo, if not, I have no idea where to even begin on a problem like this:

$P\vee (Q\wedge R), -P\wedge -Q \vdash S$

Is there something I'm missing, or is this a sequent that's impossible to derive?

I am using the following rule sets:

First 7:

https://books.google.com/books?id=qaIdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=nelson+p+lande+derivation+rules&source=bl&ots=dZSufOhmlc&sig=Ybw_RboRt2lze1CZqc8iXlyDUfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr1aWXp-bTAhXqjFQKHTjJDA0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Last 4:

https://books.google.com/books?id=qaIdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=nelson+p+lande+derivation+rules&source=bl&ots=dZSufOhmlc&sig=Ybw_RboRt2lze1CZqc8iXlyDUfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr1aWXp-bTAhXqjFQKHTjJDA0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Let me know if there is anything I can do to pose this question in a better way.

Comment: Hello there! For everybody's convenience, could you just copy the rule sets into the question rather than the links? You can either typeset them with MathJax or post images if you don't know how. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a typo. The statements are contradictory and thus by the explosion principle you can deduce anything (that's why S comes out of nowhere... it's arbitrary). I would look up a proof that you can deduce any statement from a contradiction and then prove the hypotheses are contradictory and then piece it together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see all of the rules from those links you gave ... But:

Do an $\lor$ Elim on $P \lor (Q \land R)$:

assuming $P$ will contradict with the $\neg P$, and assuming $Q \land R$ gives you $Q$ which will contradict the $\neg Q$. So, either way you get a contradiction, and from a contradiction you can infer anything you want, and what you want is of course $S$

So yes, this is valid, and can be derived, exactly because the premises are inconsistent. No typo!

OK, guessing a your rules ...

\begin{array}{llll}
1&(1)&P\lor (Q \land R)&Assumption\\
2&(2)&\neg P \land \neg Q&Assumption\\
2&(3)&\neg P& \land \ E \ 2\\
2&(4)&\neg Q& \land \ E \ 2\\
5&(5)&P&Assumption\\
6&(6)&\neg S&Assumption\\
5,6&(7)&\neg S\land P&\land \ I \ 5,6\\
5,6&(8)&P&\land\ E \ 7\\
2,5,6&(9)&P\land \neg P&\land \ I \ 3,8\\
2,5&(10)&\neg \neg S&\neg \ I \ 9\\
2,5&(11)&S&\neg \ E \ 10\\
12&(12)&Q \land R&Assumption\\
12&(13)&Q & \land \ E \ 12\\
6,12&(14)&Q\land \neg S&\land \ I \ 6,13\\
6,12&(15)&Q&\land \ E \ 14\\
2,6,12&(16)&Q \land \neg Q&\land \ I \ 4,15\\
2,12&(17)&\neg \neg S&\neg \ I \ 16\\
2,12&(18)&S&\neg \ E \ 17\\
1,2&(19)&S&\lor \ E \ 1,11,18\\
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, the main thing I've struggled with in this class is dealing with these contradictions and making my own assumptions! You're also the same user that's help me before!

Comment: @Kellen Yeah, I remember ... Did I follow the right format for the proof by contradiction (the $\neg \ I$) and the Proof by cases (the $\lor \ E$)?

Comment: Yeah! I'd worked out a solution similar from your first work, and this matches up pretty well with mine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should notice that that $\{P\vee(Q\wedge R), \neg P\wedge \neg Q\}$ is an inconsistent set of propositions.   That is that they contradict.

> Assume $P\vee (Q\wedge R)$.   *...blahblahblah...*   Therefore $P\vee(Q\wedge R)$ contradicts $\neg P\wedge\neg Q$.

Recall that a contradiction entails *anything*, vaccuously.   $S$ is something.

$\therefore\quad P\vee(Q\wedge R), \neg P\wedge \neg Q~\vdash~S$

$\blacksquare$